# Fortran Compiler Optimization

Tags: compilation, fortran, compiler-optimization

I have been working with a Fortran code written in a Visual Studio 2015 project. Since now I was always compiling and running the code using Visual Studio 2015 on my own laptop. It takes roughly 2 hours for the simulation to finish (for the code to run until completion) using a Dell personal computer with an Intel® CPU (Core™ i7-8650U-1.90GHz-4 cores-BS:2112 MHz,) and 16 GB RAM (DDR4 2400MHz) using Windows 10 (Enterprise, 64 bit).

I have recently started using a High Performance Computing (HPC) framework for compiling and running my Fortran code. The code is not parallelized and this is not quite possible (or straightforward) in my application. The HPC obviously has better specifications than my own laptop but I was surprised to see that HPC took  04:10:23 hours to finish the same simulation which took 2 hours for my laptop. Both platforms only use a single core since parallelization is not an option.

Would you have any suggestions for me to have a faster running code (at least the same time as my laptop-PC) like some compilation tips or options? I realized that turning on compiler optimizations in Visual Studio significantly (roughly 2x) reduces the run-time of simulations. Would compiling the code using specific options help for a Fortran code?

I have tried to look online for Intel compiling options but it seems really complicated for a beginner. I could not really find a road map to follow on where to look. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some recommendations or a direction to look at. I can provide additional information if necessary. Thank you very much for your time.

Here is the code I use for compilation:

```
#=============< COMPILER >=============================#
FC   = ifort
EXC = DL0D

#=============< SOURCE FILES >=========================#
SRCS = 1Main.for \
OBJS=$(SRCS:%.for=%.for)

#==============< OBJECTS FILES >=======================#
OBJECTS = Main.o \

#lsode_reduced.o utility.o
#======================================================#
COMMON =   
LIBES = -lm
FFLAGS =  -extend-source 132 -heap-arrays -O2 -g -traceback  

$(EXC) : $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
    $(RM) ./*.o ./*~

$(OBJECTS): $(COMMON)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: *The HPC obviously has better specifications than my own laptop ...* Are you sure ?  I have worked on HPC platforms where single CPUs had lower flops ratings, and less RAM available, than my laptop or workstation.

Comment: To support @HighPerformanceMark HPC platforms are usually designed so that you HAVE to use parallelism to get the best out of them - either throug job farming, or parallelising your code, or using more specialised hardware (e.g. GPUs). A single core on an old HPC machine will most likely be slower than a modern one on a laptop or workstation - if you want much faster you MUST go parallel.

Comment: I have never considered this, thank you for pointing out. I have checked the different clusters right now and these are the processors that they have: "2 x 12-core Intel E5-2680v3
(Haswell-EP @ 2.5 GHz)" and "2 x 18-core Intel Xeon Gold 6140
(Skylake @ 2.3 GHz)". I am not sure if a one to one comparison with my processor is doable, but I assume the HPC processors are not very old.

Comment: As additional information, I was able to make a comparison on 'cpubenchmark.net' but I am not sure how to interpret the results: https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Xeon-Gold-6140-vs-Intel-Xeon-E5-2680-v3-vs-Intel-i7-8650U/3132vs2390vs3070

Comment: How often do you plan to run the simulation ?  What's it worth to you to reduce the HPC run time from 4h to 3h ?  or to 2h or 1h ?  Suppose you plan to run it 400 times - how much of your own time would you invest to hit the 2h mark on the HPC platform ?  to hit the 10m mark ?  Now you have an estimate of how much of your time you should be willing to invest in (a) profiling your code to identify the hot spots (b) improving the execution of those hot spots (c) knuckling down to learn how to use compiler options to improve the speed of your code and (d) making a parallel version of the code.

Comment: In case it's not obvious from my previous comment: there is no magic bullet we can provide you to improve the run time of your code.  Code optimisation generally requires a lot more knowledge of code and platform than can easily be provided in the Q&A format supported by SO.  You will find hints and tips here, but no more than that.  Code optimisation is an experimental science, you have to experiment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight. It really widens my horizon. I am planning to use the same code multiple times (order of magnitude 1000) so it would really help to get it to run as fast as my laptop at the very least. I think I should be able to achieve this only by playing with compiler options (Please correct me if I am wrong). I think the problems with points (a), (b), and (d) should also be applicable for Visual Studio. Do you have some simple compiling tips or reading suggestions for improving point (c)?

Comment: One perfectly viable form of parallelism is job farming. Is it possible to do all the runs at once by using 1000 cores on the HPC machine at the same time? That's doing what it provides, lots and lots of cores, not a small number of very fast cores.

Comment: As to what you can do to optimize for a specific platform, you would set the instruction set for the platform, e.g. -[Q]xAVX (good for all your platforms).  Options such as -O3 may or may not take full advantage of that, or expose weaknesses in the code.  As Mark indicated, increasing the number of cores without specific parallelization could be counter-productive, so if your cluster has an option to restrict to a single core, it's worth trying.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestions, all are very helpful for me to get a good understanding of the situation. Would you have any suggestions to read on how and what to set as instruction for the platform? The intel compiler website is too complicated and I really do not know how to start. I have already tried -O2 and -O3 type of optimizations but they only slightly help. I couldn't find useful information on '-[Q]xAVX' on google. Where can I check what kind of options do I have for different compiler optimizations?

Comment: As a starting point, remove the `-g` flag and possibly also `-traceback`. The first one is likely doing most of the slow down. Unless you have specific needs, you should do very well with `-O3` alone.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try removing both to see the effects.

Comment: Since you are using the Intel compiler, use /fast (-fast on Linux) on your laptop. This sets a number of options that usually make programs run faster. One of them is /QxHost (-xhost on Linux), which optimizes for the CPU on the host doing the compilation. 

A good resource for the CPU-targeting options is https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-intel-compiler-options-for-sse-generation-and-processor-specific-optimizations/